# Merge a dictionary of Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Python 3 dictionary of Pandas DataFrame, which has the structure as follows for each DataFrame-

```
time  animal_id       x       y  Distance  Average_Speed  Average_Acceleration  Direction
0    1.0      312.0  405.29  417.76  0.000000       0.000000                   0.0   0.000000
5    2.0      312.0  405.31  417.37  0.070000       0.082164                   0.0 -90.000000
10   3.0      312.0  405.31  417.07  0.215407       0.157562                   0.0 -68.198591
15   4.0      312.0  405.30  416.86  0.192354       0.171618                   0.0 -62.102729
20   5.0      312.0  405.29  416.71  0.162788       0.182343                   0.0 -47.489553
```

The dimension/shape of each of the five Pandas DataFrame is-

```
for animal_id in data_animal_id_groups.keys():
    data_animal_id_groups[animal_id].reset_index(drop = True)

Animal ID = 312, Shape = (43201, 4)
Animal ID = 511, Shape = (43201, 4)
Animal ID = 607, Shape = (43201, 4)
Animal ID = 811, Shape = (43201, 4)
Animal ID = 905, Shape = (43201, 4)
```

I want to merge all the 5 or in general n Pandas DataFrame contained in the dictionary object into one CSV file. How should I proceed?

Please note that the structure of each Pandas DataFrame will remain the same. However, the number of rows may vary.

Thanks!

Comment: what is the key to merge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame() # Create an empty dataframe, this will be your final dataframe

for key, sub_df in data_animal_id_groups.items():
    df = df.append(sub_df, ignore_index=False) # Add your sub_df one by one

print(df)
```

And if you want to save it as a csv:

```py
df.to_csv("merged_dataframe.csv")
```

Answer (score 4):

With `dict`  you can using `concat`

```
pd.concat(data_animal_id_groups.values()) #.to_csv('youfile.csv')
```